# Return different data type data in a single function in C++

Tags: c++, json, function, templates, compiler-errors

Please find the below code.

```
template<typename T>
T GetValueFromDataType(Value &value)
{
    T jsonValue;
    if (value.IsString())
    {
        assert(value.IsString());
        jsonValue = value.GetString();  // Here the error is showing
        return jsonValue;
    }
    else if (value.IsInt())
    {
        assert(value.IsInt());
        jsonValue = value.GetInt();
        return jsonValue;
    }
    else if (value.IsDouble())
    {
        assert(value.IsDouble());
        jsonValue = value.GetDouble();
        return jsonValue;
    }
    else if (value.IsBool())
    {
        assert(value.IsBool());
        jsonValue = value.GetBool();
        return jsonValue;
    }
}
```

The `jsonValue` is returned in another function. There I have declared the return variable as int. Ideally, it should take the *int* case. But it's giving a compilation error:

> Error C2440 '=': cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'int'

Is there a way to use the above code or another construct?

Comment: the code doesn't make much sense, why you `assert` after an `if`

Comment: maybe you want to use `constexpr if` (even so it's most likely not in the way the above code currently shows)

Comment: This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: its rapidjson where asert required otherwise it give error

Answer (score 1):

If you call `GetValueFromDataType<int>(...)`, then `jsonValue` inside has type `int` and `jsonValue = value.GetString();` isn't going to have any sense. It doesn't matter that `value.IsString()` is false and that you have an `assert` in there that is going to fail. If code is there, it needs to be valid—unless you specifically exclude it from consideration by using `if constexpr`. The not-taken branch of `if constexpr` is not instantiated, so the code inside only undergoes lightweight checking (just like in an uninstantiated template). It doesn't have to be type-correct.

Bad:

```
assert(value.IsString());
jsonValue = value.GetString();      // this line will be fully checked
                                    // regardless of the condition above
```

Good:

```
if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>) {
   assert(value.IsString());        // make sure the value matches
   jsonValue = value.GetString();   // this line will NOT be fully checked
                                    // if the condition in the if statement
                                    // (known at compile time) is false.
}
```

Having said that, I dislike this style and prefer explicit specialisations if possible.

```
template<typename T>
T GetValueFromDataType(Value &value);

template <>
std::string GetValueFromDataType<std::string>(Value &value) {
    assert(value.IsString());
    return value.GetString();
}
// etc.
```

The reason is that it is more modular. We don't have to touch existing functions if a new type is added.

Comment: Hi,  I tried the above code but giving errors. One error is 
Error C2059 syntax error: 'type'

Comment: @TechnologyEnthusiast Fix them. You have your entire code including the definition of `Value`. I don't.